# VSTO-Addins (Word, Excel) with similar functions: Outsource into own project

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

I am currently working on an major recode of a project I created some time ago.

It consists of two VSTO-AddIns, one for Excel and one for Word. These AddIns do have almost the same things to do, but differ in details like the data-object. In Word it is a Document, in Excel Workbooks are used. So I can't just copy and paste the code between the AddIns.

Because of that, I created the same stuff for both AddIns manually. This causes a lot of redundant code in both projects. This is a pain to maintain.

So for this refactoring I favor using a central Project both AddIns access exactly the same way.

This is how I got it working with my prior Word-AddIn as example:
[image: Old]

Now I moved the whole Word_PropertyReadWrite into a own Project (a class library) and want to merge it with the Excel_PropertyReadWrite which exists parallel to Word_PropertyReadWrite atm. Before moving, both classes implemented IPropertyReadWrite. I think this will be needed now too, so I keep at it and also moved the interface into the new classlibrary.

This seems to work up until now, I have to create a class which redirects calls for the specific methods to the interface. These still need to exist in both AddIns parallel, but there is way less code to be maintained and the redundancy there is likely to be very hard to be terminated, though it would be nice to get rid of that, too.

But, and this is the problem I am having now, I seem to not being able to get all methods to work in this new class library.

Specific:
I can't use the Globals-Variables I need to open documents/workbooks.
I have this Open-Method, which worked before:

```
/// <summary>
/// Opens the file at the given path.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Path">File's full path</param>
/// <returns>Returns success.</returns>
public bool Open(string Path)
{
  //Checks, if there is already an file open. This code is not good, I know that, 
  //but it got the job done. This will get thrown out, since I want to get multithreating 
  //to work ;)
  if (IsInUse)
  {
    log.Warn("Es ist bereits eine Datei offen und in Bearbeitung");
    return false;
  }

  try
  {
    Document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Open(FileName: Path, 
                ConfirmConversions: false, ReadOnly: false, AddToRecentFiles: false, 
                Revert: false, Visible: false, OpenAndRepair: true, NoEncodingDialog: false);
    IsInUse = true;
    Orig_FullPath = Path;
    Orig_FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path);
    Orig_DirectoryPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Path);
    log.Debug("Open war erfolgreich");
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    log.Error(string.Format("Beim Öffnen der Datei ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.\nPfad: {0}",
                             Path), ex);
    return false;
  }
}
```

The specific line to create problems is:

```
Document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Open...
```

The use of Globals is not possible outside of the AddIn's project, since it accesses, in this case, Word itself.
Any attemp of referencing maybe ThisAddIn or Application failed until now.
The only way I see this would fit is by keeping all methods making use of this functionality in the AddIns.

But this would make the code, in my opinion, worse to maintain, because then there will be, again, more redundant code and I would tear maybe 2 or 3 methods out of the cleanly separated AddInFunctions-class. (Here is the new layout of my new class:)
[image: New class-files]

So, is it possible to outsource all of these methods to an class library and if so, how is this achived?

Comment: I don´t think this will work, because the addins can not do the same stuff. In word you have documents ind excel you have workbooks and worksheets. So in fact you have apples (word) and bananas (excel) and want to have a fruit salad (Office) this doesn´t work --> I tried that several times for years now. You can do this, but it will be the way you told in your question: code will get worse to maintain!

Comment: @MarcelTheis Hm, you may be right, but if you look at the methods names, I really do stuff that is existing in both cases. I have this programm, that changes DocumentProperties and nothing else. Ofc I need to differ between Excel and Word, but in the end I access in both cases the "same" values, just through different paths. The difficulty lays in getting the Globals. Everything else has been done before ;)